# Insert/Update in asp.net and SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, insert-update

I am trying to insert a record if requested `prodName` doesnot exist in database. If it exists I want to update the value of `quantity` attribute. I have used the following it neither inserts nor Updates any record. I get following exception:

`ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed`

This is the code

```
public static void manageStock(CompanyStock stock)
    {
        ///// Check if record exists/////////
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from tblStock where prodName=@prodName", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName", stock.prodName);
        con.Open();
        Int32 count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //returns null if doesnt exist
        con.Close();

        if (count > 0)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("update tblStock set quantity = @quantity where prodName=@prodName", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName", stock.prodName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", stock.quantity);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblStock(prodName,quantity) values (@prodName, @quantity)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName",stock.prodName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity",stock.quantity);
        }

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edited** 
I edited my code. It works fine now. I had to open my connection before executing `ExecuteScalar` But I want to know the standard way of writing this opening and closing stuff. It looks kind of haphazard. How can I improve this?

Comment: I believe you need to open the connection before your execute the first command object. I am not sure how your code executes. If this is indeed the code, it will always execute the INSERT into tblStock command.

Comment: What is wrong with your code is that you do not handle your exceptions so you cannot see error messages that might tell you what the problem really is.

Comment: @Pleun With no `catch`, though, won't they just bubble up? Though it sounds like there's probably something further on the stack swallowing somewhere.

Comment: Edited my question. Please have a look again

Answer (score 0):

You can use Convert.ToInt32() method for converting the result into integer value.

if the value is `null` it converts it into `0`.

Try This:

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using MERGE clause in sql-server.  Here is a good [Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) you can use.

Answer (score 0):

What does it do when you step through the code?

In some SQL collations (Latin1_General_BIN for example), variables are case sensitive.  In your first select statement you have @`P`rodName in your query and @`p`rodName in your parameters collection.  If you have a case sensitive collation, you're never getting past this part.  Right-click on the database in Management Studio and click Properties to find the collation.

Comment: After re-reading your edit, on your SELECT  line, you're supplying it with a `con` connection, but I don't see that it was opened.

Comment: I opened it. Problem is solved now but it doesnot look neat. Please check

Comment: That's the way it works.  Maybe look into writing a database wrapper http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553846/c-sharp-database-wrapper-design

Answer (score 0):

Error say that there's no connection.May u check first of all that issue so

Check connection and if is not null and exist at this point check it con.State = Open or any other value. I connection state is closed open it.But first of all where is connections declaration ? i don't see it in your code.

TRY THIS :

```
//USING THE STATEMNET USING IT WILL TAKE CARE TO DISPOSE CONNECTION AND PLACE TRY CATCH WITHIN PROCS

{
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("connectionString"))) {
    if (cnn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        cnn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) {
        try {
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            cmd.CommandText = "YOUR SQL STATEMENT";
            int I = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery);

            if (I > 0)
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "YOUR SQL STATEMENT";
            //ADDITIONAL PARAMTERES
            } 
            else
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "YOUR SQL STATEMENT";
                //ADDITIONAL PARAMETERS
            }
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            } 
              catch (Exception ex) 
            {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look to my solution it was more simple and safe.Never left connection open remeber :). It it match your goal make this as answers

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. First write a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sprocquanupdateinsert
    @prodName nvarchar(250),
    @quantity int
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE tblStock 
    SET quantity = @quantity 
    WHERE prodName = @prodName

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        INSERT INTO tblStock(prodName, quantity) 
        VALUES (@prodName, @quantity)
END
GO
```

Then in code behind you can use this

```
using (conn)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sprocquanupdateinsert", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName", stock.prodName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", stock.quantity);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```