# Is this code thread safe in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, thread-safety

Based on my current understanding I do not think this code is thread safe but want to confirm. In other words I think that, although it would be extremely unlikely, multiple threads representing different HTTP requests could potentially mix up the value of the `_userName` property.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private static string _userName;

    public static string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_userName))
            {
                _userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            }

            return _userName; 
        }
    }
}
```

Is it thread-safe and if not would removing the null check, and always accessing `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` directly (in a static property) be thread-safe?

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, your first example is not thread-safe because static members are shared between threads (unless you're using thread-local storage, which you're not), and the `HttpContext.Current` property **is** stored in thread-local storage.

Comment: Also, there's a second thread-safety issue: your thread could be preempted between the `if` and `=` statements so you'd want a `lock`, not that he code is a good idea in the first place.

Comment: "although it would be extremely unlikely" It's probably much more likely than you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second solution would work fine. The first one is **not thread safe at all**. Caching a value in a static variable exposes it to all threads, and if you have two or more simultaneous requests, it's highly likely they will read some other request's value. You think it's *extremely unlikely*, well... it's not, quite the opposite.

Besides, if you really want a value to be shared across multiple threads, you should use some synchronization mechanism to ensure correctness. In your first example, you access `_userName` 3 times (2 reads and 1 write). You can get into a situation where this variable ends up different values, so you should enclose everything in a `lock`. And that's only when you explicitly want to share this information between threads.

The second approach works because the value of `HttpContext.Current` is retrieved from the current [execution context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.executioncontext.aspx) (so it's dependent on the current thread).

Oh one more thing: in an ASP.NET application you shouldn't rely on thread-local storage because of [thread agility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11306888/3764814), so if you need to cache values use the `HttpContext` instead. You have an `Items` property which lets you store values for the duration of the current request only. but in your particular example, you don't have to cache this value, because it's already retrieved from the HTTP context.

Answer (score 3):

Your two examples are *very different*.  You are right in that your first example is not thread safe, but the more important problem is that *it's not session-safe*.  The first session that accesses `UserName` will set the username, and *all other sessions will use that same name*!  `UserName` will not change until the App pool is recycled.  Does it matter that *technically* the *second* session set the user name if it made the request just slightly after the first?

If you want to cache the user name for each session then use the `Session` property:

```
Session["UserName"] = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

The second block *is* thread-safe, but it returns the current user name *every time it's called*.  So there's no worry about data getting crossed across threads, let alone sessions.

Comment: "UserName will not change until the App pool is recycled."

How sure are you about this part? That doesn't seem to be how it behaves but I'll look into it more. I am thinking it would come down to when the implicit static constructor is called for the class -- wouldn't the static constructor clear _userName every time it is called? Is it called only once for the life of the process?

Comment: @SeanThoman static properties are static for the whole app pool.  The first time someone tries to read the `UserName` property the current session's user is extracted and the static field is set - unless you have other code that changes that field it will stay the same value until the process dies.

Answer (score 1):

2

Your second solution would work fine. The first one is not thread safe at all. Caching a value in a static variable exposes it to all threads, and if you have two or more simultaneous requests, it's highly likely they will read some other request's value. You think it's extremely unlikely, well... it's not, quite the opposite.