# Not awaiting an Async method which in turn has an await in it

Tags: c#, asynchronous

```cs
public void button_push()
{
    genericMethodAsync();
    SynchronousCode1();
}

public async void genericMethodAsync()
{
     await someOtherAsyncMethod();
     SynchronousCode2();
     SyncronousCode3();
}
```

Let's say I have a button that calls an async method, but doesn't await it. However, the async method that the button calls does have an await.
I assume that because the button click doesn't await the method, `SynchronousCode1()` may execute before `SynchronousCode2()`.

Let's say the async method that is awaited takes a long time, like 2 seconds, and is an IO bound task. Will the `SynchronousCode2()` method finish on the same thread (or should I say same context) that that the `button_push()` method was called on?
I wasn't sure about this since the `button_Push()` command may run to completion before the await is finished in the async method.

Comment: `void button_push` does not involve async code, so it has not reason to switch threads. `void genericMethodAsync` contains an `await` which captures the context, so `SynchronousCode2` should execute on that context. Thus, `SynchronousCode1` and `SynchronousCode2` should run on the same context/thread. That is no reason to do it this way though.

Comment: You can't get any warranty for this kind of code.  The detail that everybody *likes* to overlook, but never should, is what will happen when the user closes the window before those two seconds expire.  Or presses the button again.

Comment: @Hans: _"what will happen when the user closes the window"_ -- that only matters if the window that was closed causes the thread's message loop to terminate. Many windows won't, and getting into a discussion about when and how that might happen would unnecessarily complicate the discussion. I think it's reasonable for the sake of simplicity to "overlook" issues like that.

Comment: I understand that this is a terrible way to do it.  I’ve read all the practices that are considered the “right” way to use async/await. I am more or less trying to understand what is happening in various scenarios, despite if they involve good or bad practices. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume that because the button click doesn't await the method, `SynchronousCode1()` may execute before `SynchronousCode2()`.

Yes, that is correct. It will depend on the implementation of `someOtherAsyncMethod()`. But assuming that method does not complete synchronously (as is its right), then it will eventually yield, causing the `await someOtherAsyncMethod()` to yield to the caller, which will allow the `SynchronousCode1()` method to be called, potentially before the `someOtherAsyncMethod()` method has completed (and definitely before then, as long as the asynchronous completion of `someOtherAsyncMethod()` is of any significant length of time).

> Let's say the async method that is awaited takes a long time, like 2 seconds, and is an IO bound task. Will the SynchronousCode2() method finish on the same thread (or should I say same context) that that the button_push() method was called on?

Given the code you posted, and making the assumption that the code is executed in a typical UI thread (i.e. one with a thread-specific synchronization context), then yes, the `SynchronousCode2()` method will be executed in the same thread where the `button_push()` method was originally called.

Answer (score 3):

> I assume that because the button click doesn't await the method, SynchronousCode1() may execute before SynchronousCode2().

Correct

> Let's say the async method that is awaited takes a long time, like 2 seconds, and is an IO bound task. Will the SynchronousCode2() method finish on the same thread (or should I say same context) that that the button_push() method was called on?

Everything within the `button_push` method will execute on the same thread. Because it never uses `await`, it never yields control. All it does is post a new task onto a queue then move on to executing the rest of its code.

As for `SynchronousCode2()`, yes, there is a chance it will execute on a different thread or different context. It depends completely on how the synchronization context works. In the case of a console application (which has no synchronization context other than the thread pool) it could very likely be on a different thread. In an ASP.NET application running on the .NET framework, it will be on the same thread (subject to [thread agility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306888/what-is-the-meaning-of-thread-agility-in-asp-net)) and the same context. In an .NET Core application [it could be different](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html). In a WinForms app (where the synchronization is provided by the default message pump) it will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

## *It's All About the SynchronizationContext* (and `ConfigureAwait`)

The behaviour will depend on the current [SynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.8):

> The purpose of the synchronization model implemented by this class is to allow the internal asynchronous/synchronous operations of the common language runtime to behave properly with different synchronization models.

### `ConfigureAwait`

With [`ConfigureAwait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait?view=netframework-4.8) you can affect the continuation behaviour.

> Parameters
>
> `continueOnCapturedContext` Boolean
>
> `true` to attempt to marshal the continuation back to the original context captured; otherwise, `false`.

### WPF

Your example is likely from a WPF app and will use `DispatcherSynchronizationContext`. Here is a passage from 
[Parallel Computing - It's All About the SynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/february/msdn-magazine-parallel-computing-it-s-all-about-the-synchronizationcontext) about it.

> **DispatcherSynchronizationContext** (WindowsBase.dll: System.Windows.Threading) WPF and Silverlight applications use a DispatcherSynchronizationContext, which queues delegates to the UI thread’s Dispatcher with “Normal” priority. This SynchronizationContext is installed as the current context when a thread begins its Dispatcher loop by calling Dispatcher.Run. The context for DispatcherSynchronizationContext is a single UI thread.
>
> All delegates queued to the DispatcherSynchronizationContext are executed one at a time by a specific UI thread in the order they were queued. The current implementation creates one DispatcherSynchronizationContext for each top-level window, even if they all share the same underlying Dispatcher.

## Examples

### 1. WPF, no `.ConfigureAwait`

In the context of a WPF app with no `.ConfigureAwait(false)`  `SynchronousCode2` would be executed in the same thread.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Print($"SynchronizationContext.Current: {SynchronizationContext.Current}");
        Print("\t button_push START");
        genericMethodAsync();
        Print("\t button_push END");
    }

    public async void genericMethodAsync()
    {
        Print("\t\t genericMethodAsync START");
        await someOtherAsyncMethod();
        Print("\t\t genericMethodAsync calling SynchronousCode2");
        SynchronousCode2();
        Print("\t\t genericMethodAsync END");
    }

    private void SynchronousCode2()
    {
        Print("\t\t\t SynchronousCode2 START");
        Print("\t\t\t SynchronousCode2 END");
    }

    private async Task someOtherAsyncMethod()
    {
        Print("\t\t\t someOtherAsyncMethod START");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        Print("\t\t\t someOtherAsyncMethod END");
    }

    private static void Print(string v) =>
        Console.WriteLine($"T{System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: {v}");
}
```

```
T1: SynchronizationContext.Current: System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext
T1:      button_push START
T1:          genericMethodAsync START
T1:              someOtherAsyncMethod START
T1:      button_push END
T1:              someOtherAsyncMethod END
T1:          genericMethodAsync calling SynchronousCode2
T1:              SynchronousCode2 START
T1:              SynchronousCode2 END
T1:          genericMethodAsync END
```

### 3. WPF, with `.ConfigureAwait`

If `ConfigureAwait(false)` is used, then `SynchronousCode2` may be called by another thread.

```
await someOtherAsyncMethod().ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
```

Output

```
T1: SynchronizationContext.Current: System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext
T1:      button_push START
T1:          genericMethodAsync START
T1:              someOtherAsyncMethod START
T1:      button_push END
T1:              someOtherAsyncMethod END
T9:          genericMethodAsync calling SynchronousCode2
T9:              SynchronousCode2 START
T9:              SynchronousCode2 END
T9:          genericMethodAsync END
```

### 3. No context

In a context of a console application. The result will be different. `SynchronousCode2` may or may not be executed by the same thread.

```
public void button_push()
{
    Print("\t button_push START");
    genericMethodAsync();
    Print("\t button_push END");
}

public async void genericMethodAsync()
{
    Print("\t\t genericMethodAsync START");
    await someOtherAsyncMethod();
    Print("\t\t genericMethodAsync calling SynchronousCode2");
    SynchronousCode2();
    Print("\t\t genericMethodAsync END");
}

private void SynchronousCode2()
{
    Print("\t\t\t SynchronousCode2 START");
    Print("\t\t\t SynchronousCode2 END");

}

private async Task someOtherAsyncMethod()
{
    Print("\t\t\t someOtherAsyncMethod START");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    Print("\t\t\t someOtherAsyncMethod END");
}

private static void Print(string v) =>
    Console.WriteLine($"T{System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: {v}");

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Print(" Main START");
    new Program().button_push();
    Print(" Main after button_push");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

```
// .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0
T1: Main START
T1: SynchronizationContext.Current: null
T1:      button_push START
T1:          genericMethodAsync START
T1:              someOtherAsyncMethod START
T1:      button_push END
T1: Main after button_push
T4:              someOtherAsyncMethod END
T4:          genericMethodAsync calling SynchronousCode2
T4:              SynchronousCode2 START
T4:              SynchronousCode2 END
T4:          genericMethodAsync END
```

---

## Note on `async avoid`

Generally speaking `async void` should be avoided but event handlers are the exception.

The other very important rule is not to block the UI thread.

You could make `button_push` `async`, make `genericMethodAsync` return `Task` and make things more predictable.

```
public async void button_push()
{
    await genericMethodAsync();
    SynchronousCode1();
}

async Task genericMethodAsync()
{
     await someOtherAsyncMethodAsync();
     SynchronousCode2();
     SyncronousCode3();
}
```