# Does a .NET service exhibit thread agility?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-services

Related to questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657735/how-is-asp-net-multithreaded) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306888/what-is-the-meaning-of-thread-agility-in-asp-net) about ASP.NET thread agility: Can a windows service written in C# exhibit the same thread agility behavior seen in ASP.NET?  Or is thread agility more a feature of IIS than .NET?

Really what I'm after is can I be sure that thread management within a windows service is entirely up to the service itself?  Or can .NET hop threads within a long-running service if it chooses to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  A windows service is not managed by the IIS pipeline and any threads that are created must be created by the service code itself.

Comment: OK, so thread agility is more a feature of IIS than the .NET framework.  That's what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 3):

Thread agility is IIS specific. Windows service will not have that behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Thread agility is a property of how the thread pool mechanism interacts with asynchronous I/O. You can implement a similar mechanism yourself, but it isn't an automatic behavior.