# Is thread agility IIS specific

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, threadpool

I have been reading some post on the possible problems thread agility could cause in .Net and would like to know where to look out for these kind of problems.

Reading a few Posts including the following:

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html

http://piers7.blogspot.de/2005/11/threadstatic-callcontext-and_02.html

http://www.lhotka.net/WeBlog/PermaLink,guid,019e3c37-38ed-492e-b769-16e1a57fed0a.aspx

I am not sure whether thread agility is only a Problem when the IIS is involed like the folllowing SO answers indicate:

[What is the meaning of thread-agility in ASP.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306888/what-is-the-meaning-of-thread-agility-in-asp-net)

[Does a .NET service exhibit thread agility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30404070/does-a-net-service-exhibit-thread-agility)

Could an application only hosting a Web.API and WCF services be affected?