# Localizing an ASP.NET application: Why shouldn't I use Page.Culture?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, localization

So far, I was under the impression that ASP.NET web forms localization works by overriding `Page.InitializeCulture` and setting `Page.Culture` and/or `Page.UICulture` according to some user choice. In fact, the [documentation of Page.InitializeCulture even says so](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initializeculture(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The InitializeCulture method contains no coding logic. Control developers extending the functionality of the Page class can override the InitializeCulture method to initialize the [Culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.culture(v=vs.110).aspx) and [UICulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.uiculture(v=vs.110).aspx) information for the page.

However, following the link to `Culture` or `UICulture` yields the following warning:

> This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

Is the warning rubbish or am I on the wrong track and localization should be done in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

The intended way is, I believe:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

The [`Page.UICulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.uiculture(v=vs.110).aspx) entry on MSDN later says:

> This property is a shortcut for the CurrentThread property. The
>   culture is a property of the executing thread

I would say the warning is mostly nonsense, as it just shortcuts to the thread method of doing it.

Tho I wouldn't, personally, set the culture on the `Page`, I'd do it somewhere in the `global.ascx`. E.g. `Application_BeginRequest` or `Application_Start`.
That way the culture is set before the Page Lifecycle has kicked in.

Potentially, that is the direction the warning is pointing you towards.

Comment: Makes sense. From a stylistic point of view, I'd rather use the Page properties than the Thread properties, since [a single aspx request can change the thread during the lifecycle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/657748/87698), and I actually want to set the culture of the *current request* rather than the one of the *thread* (which is an implementation detail of the ASP.NET execution engine).